# Animating Violin and Bow - Constrain Rigid Body Between 2 Moving Points

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints

Here is a challenge for animation gurus...I am attempting to add a violin and bow to a model with a mocap violin performance. The Mocap has worked quite well, and I have been able to rotate the and pose the hands of the bow (RH) and the violin (LH). I have added bones to the bow and violin, and constrained the bow to the RH of the model armature, and so it is moving quite well with the bow arm, and the violin to the LH of the model. It works - after a fashion.

What I'd like to do is be able to constrain the bow's rotation so that it matches the violin. Mocamp doesn't capture the intricate movements of the bow hand (understandably), but if I could find a way to parent or constrain the bow to an empty attached to the violin, the RH bow arm could drive the local Z axis of the bow, and the violin RH arm could control its world position via the empty, thus keeping the bow positioned on the strings whilst being "bowed".

I've gotten close, but no cigar as yet. I feel sure this is doable, and I'm not miles off. What about a nurb path? I just can't quite figure out how. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Consider a track to constraint

Comment: That's a little cryptic....so would I track the bone of the bow to be constrained by the empty on the violin? So how would blender know what location information to interpolate in order to move with one constraint (the bow hand animation) and the other (the violin hand animation)? I'll give it a go but any other information would be most welcome.